# Analytical solution to homogenous Heat equation with non-homogenous Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dirac-delta, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

Given :

$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}=\alpha\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x^2}}$

Boundary conditions :

$\frac{\partial{u(0,t)}}{\partial{x}}=\delta(t)=-\frac{q}{\lambda}$

$\frac{\partial{u(L,t)}}{\partial{x}}=0$

$u(x,0)=T_0=298,15K$

$0<x<L$, $L=1mm$

$t>0$

I am looking for a response of the system at *x = L* to see a temperature rise at the end of the rod and plot *T(x=L,t)* to find how much time is needed to reach peak temperature. I've tried homogenizing the problem and used SoV by assuming *u(x,t) = w(x,t) + v(x,t)*

$\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{t}}=\alpha\frac{\partial^2{w}}{\partial{x^2}}+\alpha\frac{\partial^2{v}}{\partial{x^2}}$

Where $w(x,t)=Ax^2+Bx+Ct$

Then

$\alpha\frac{\partial^2{w(x,t)}}{\partial{x^2}}=2A\alpha=\frac{\partial{w(x,t)}}{\partial{t}}=C$

$\frac{\partial{w(0,t)}}{\partial{x}}=B=-\frac{q}{\lambda}$, $\frac{\partial{w(L,t)}}{\partial{x}}=2AL+B=0$

I was left with

$\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{t}}=\alpha\frac{\partial^2{v}}{\partial{x^2}}$

Boundary conditions :

$\frac{\partial{v(0,t)}}{\partial{x}}=0$

$\frac{\partial{v(L,t)}}{\partial{x}}=0$

$v(x,0)=T_0-w(x,0)=\phi(x)$

My solution is $u(x,t)=w(x,t)+\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty cos(\mu_nx)e^{-\mu_n^2\alpha t}$

$a_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^L\phi(x)cos(\mu_nx)dx$

But I coudn't slove it with $\delta(t)$, because then $a_n=0$, $a_0=T_0$, $v(x,t)=T_0$ and everything blows up, which is non-physical. By replacing $\delta(t)$ with $-\frac{q}{\lambda}$ I found the solution, but This is what happens at *x = L= 1 mm*

[Evolution of temperature at *x=L*. I used constants such as $\alpha$,$\lambda$ etc. for iron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSmlC.jpg)

Can someone help me to compute it with $\delta(t)$ in B.Cs?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by $\delta(t)$ here, is it the unit Dirac delta in time, or what is it? Are you solving the case with $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x=0)=-q/\lambda$ and if so why even introduce $\delta(t)$ as a symbol?

Comment: In any case I see an immediate problem in your derivation which is that your form of $w$ does not vanish under the differential operator, so $v$ will need to satisfy the heat equation with homogeneous boundary data but nontrivial forcing.

Comment: I see another problem which is that your boundary conditions *will* blow everything up, unless the BC on the left dissipates over time, because you are always adding (or removing, whatever) heat in on the left (regardless of how hot the rod already is) and are not losing heat out the right. So for this $-q/\lambda$ case you should probably be using a Robin condition instead of a Neumann condition.

Comment: Thank you Ian! I will try to correct it! I was trying to solve it for −q/λ but I am looking for a solution to this problem with unit Dirac delta. In this case $\delta(t-0)$ means unitary impulse of heat at x=0

Comment: That is then the same as adding $\delta(x)$ to whatever your initial data was and then evolving that with homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions.

Comment: Or actually $-\alpha \delta(x)$ (positive derivative on the left corresponds to outward flux, and the diffusion coefficient enters).